# How to extend ghc-typelits-natnormalise to check relationships between universally and existentially quantified types?

Tags: haskell, types, proxy, ghc, existential-type

I'm trying to make my use of `Finite`s completely safe and non-partial, by using `Proxy`s in place of `Integer`s like so:

```
-- SO test case, re: my use of ghc-typelits-natnormalise package.
--
-- David Banas <capn.freako@gmail.com>
-- February 9, 2018

{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fplugin GHC.TypeLits.Normalise #-}

{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

module Bogus.NewFin where

import GHC.TypeLits
import Data.Proxy
import Data.Finite
import Data.Finite.Internal (Finite(..))
import Data.Reflection

-- A safer form of `finite`.
finite' :: (KnownNat n, KnownNat m, n `CmpNat` m ~ 'GT) => Proxy m -> Finite n
finite' p = Finite $ natVal p

-- A safer form of `getFinite`.
getFinite' :: KnownNat n => Finite n -> (forall m. (KnownNat m, n `CmpNat` m ~ 'GT) => Proxy m -> r) -> r
getFinite' x f = reifyNat (getFinite x) f
```

And I'm getting this compiler error:

```
Davids-Air-2:test dbanas$ stack ghc -- -c so_natnorm.hs 

so_natnorm.hs:28:41: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘CmpNat n n1’ with ‘'GT’
        arising from a use of ‘f’
    • In the second argument of ‘reifyNat’, namely ‘f’
      In the expression: reifyNat (getFinite x) f
      In an equation for ‘getFinite'’:
          getFinite' x f = reifyNat (getFinite x) f
    • Relevant bindings include
        f :: forall (m :: Nat).
             (KnownNat m, CmpNat n m ~ 'GT) =>
             Proxy m -> r
          (bound at so_natnorm.hs:28:14)
        x :: Finite n (bound at so_natnorm.hs:28:12)
        getFinite' :: Finite n
                      -> (forall (m :: Nat).
                          (KnownNat m, CmpNat n m ~ 'GT) =>
                          Proxy m -> r)
                      -> r
          (bound at so_natnorm.hs:28:1)
```

I'm guessing that my problem is trying to relate a universally and an existentially quantified type, through the mechanisms provided by the *ghc-typelits-natnormalise* package. Is that correct?

It seems to me that this ought to be allowed, since the caller is responsible for assigning both:

- the value of `n`, and
- the maximum value of `m`.

Where is my reasoning about this faulty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reifyNat` takes as an argument a function which works for *any* natural. A function of type `` forall m. (KnownNat m, n `CmpNat` m ~ 'GT) => Proxy m -> r `` doesn't work on any natural; it only works on naturals less than some other `n`.

Since you are calling `getFinite` to produce the actual value, you know that value is less than `n`. Unfortunately, you have no way to prove this to the typechecker. Fortunately, you are allowed to tell the typechecker to trust you:

```
import Type.Reflection ((:~:)(..))
import Unsafe.Coerce

...

getFinite'' :: KnownNat n => Finite n -> (forall m. (KnownNat m) => Proxy m -> n `CmpNat` m :~: 'GT -> r) -> r
getFinite'' x f = reifyNat (getFinite x) $ \p -> f p (unsafeCoerce Refl)

getFinite' :: forall n r . KnownNat n => Finite n -> (forall m. (KnownNat m, n `CmpNat` m ~ 'GT) => Proxy m -> r) -> r
getFinite' x f = getFinite'' x $ \p Refl -> f p
```